# After updating to 2.81, my previous works (done in 2.80) doesn't show colors

Tags: color

[image: Rendered Image]

This image is what's supposed to look like in Edit Mode/Object Mode(although I still can make these screenshots even after the update by pressing F12 which is rendering) but the following is what my donut looks like now in Blender.

[image: Error]

It shows no shadows and colors. The only thing I did is updating blender to 2.81 from 2.80. And I don't know what but something seems off with blender. Sometimes I can't click any objects so I just pressed tab and then now it's all clickable. Seems like I was in edit mode, but to me, it looked exactly like object mode.

I don't know what is wrong with it. How do I make my colors show up again?

Comment: Hello :). You're now in *Solid view* where colors don't appear. Switch to *Material preview* or *Rendered preview*, and your colors will all be there :).

Comment: @JachymMichal Thanks for the comment. But I do not know what is Solid View. And how do I switch to Material preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're now in *Solid view* where colors don't appear.
Switch to *Material preview* or *Rendered preview*, and your colors will all be there :)

[image]

Good luck with your donut :).