# Why I change the base color, nothing happened? but when I change viewport display color it change

Tags: 3d-view, color

Why I change the base color, nothing happened? but when I change viewport display color it change. 
[image: The plane there, I change the color at viewport color option]

Comment: Because you are currently viewing the display color

Comment: Hello and welcome :). [You need to switch to material preview.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160482/78972)